# How can update object in prisma?

Tags: node.js, prisma

How to change the status of information using prism, I tried using set and looked in the official doc, I didn't find anything

for example I have a class Car it has a name and active, I wanted to do an update that would just set the active to false

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found a example in the prisma documentation.
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions

```
// Change the active status of a car
const updatedCar: Car = await prisma.car.update({
  where: { id: 1 /* use any filter here */ },
  data: { /* pass the new car informations here */
    active: false
  },
})
```

You can use "prisma.car.updateMany" to update many rows of the database table.